# system and CreateProcess()

Tags: c, windows

I have a command,I need to execute the same using C Program.
I have stored the entire command ,with arguments, in the variable cmdline.
When I am using system(cmdline),it is working fine.
But on using the following:
ret = CreateProcess(NULL,
                        cmdline,
                        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
                        (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)NULL,
                        TRUE,
                        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        &startup,
                        &pinfo);

I am getting the return code as 2 in GetLastError().

Can somebody tell the reason?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the entire code used for CreateProcess? It may happen that you didn't zeroed out startup and pinfo structures.

Comment: Command is user defined.
Also,I have zeroed out  startup and pinfo structures before calling create startup

Comment: Still you'll be much better of if you post an example command here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the program name contains whitespace?

From MSDN: If lpApplicationName is NULL, the first white-space – delimited token of the command line specifies the module name. If you are using a long file name that contains a space, use quoted strings to indicate where the file name ends and the arguments begin.

Comment: +1  If the OP is getting file-not-found, this is the most likely explanation.